# Outlier correction in Python

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I have a list of numbers like:

```
[10
20
2
40
50
60
70
80
0
100]
```

I want to replace digit by doing average of previous two values and next two values incase it is less than average of list. Like here 2 will be replaced by average of (10,20,40,50) ie 30. Similary incase it reaches 0 at the second last occurance ,now it dont have next two occurences , in that case it should take average of previous three and the next one to maintain count of 4 values ie average of (60,70,80,100) ie 77.5. Can anybody guide me with the best possible logic . Final output is:

```
[10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
77.6
100]
```

Comment: Average of list is `43.2`. `10` and `20` are less than average of the list. why don't you replace it?

Comment: If you are measuring real values, it is not a standard treatment, to replace outliers in such a way.  If there is missing data, such as a NaN value, one method of dealing with that, is replace the NaN value with the mean of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def correct_outliers(s, threshold, n_prev=3, n_next=1):
    local_s = s.copy()
    updated_index = local_s.to_frame().apply(lambda x: correct_outlier(x, local_s, threshold), axis=1)
    return local_s

def correct_outlier(x, s, threshold, n_prev=3, n_next=1):
    if x.isna()[0] or x[0] < threshold:
        lower_index, upper_index = get_fixed_index(x.name, n_prev, n_next)
        s[x.name] = s.loc[lower_index:x.name-1].append(s.loc[x.name+1:upper_index]).mean(skipna=True)
        return True
    return False
```

#### Explanation and considerations

1. I used `pandas.Series` to work with data
2. The `correct_outliers` function receives as input a pandas series, a
   `threshold` value and the window bounds (`n_prev` and `n_nex`)
3. The `correct_outlier` function is called by `correct_outliers` and
   is applied, element by element, to the series in input using
   `series.apply`
4. The `get_fixed_bounds` function given the index of the current element `i` and the values ​​of the bounds of the window taking
   into account your requests formulated by you in the application
5. The core of the `correct_outlier` function is the following: 
   If the
   current value of the series is less than the `threshold` value, then
   the current value of the series is replaced by the `average`
   calculated in the interval defined by the fixed bounds (excluding the
   null values ​​and the current value)

#### Example

Given the following data series:

```
s = pd.Series([10, 20, 2, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 0, 100], dtypes='float')
0     10.0
1     20.0
2      2.0
3     40.0
4     50.0
5     60.0
6     70.0
7     80.0
8      0.0
9    100.0
```

Define a threshold value and the windows:

```
threshold = 5   # s.mean(skipna=True) in your example
n_prev = 3      # 3 element before the current
n_next = 1      # 1 element after the current
```

Now call the correct_outliers:

```
fixed_series = correct_outliers(s, n_prev, n_next, threshold), axis=1)
```

And gives:

```
0   10.0
1   20.0
2   30.0
3   40.0
4   50.0
5   60.0
6   70.0
7   80.0
8   77.5
9  100.0
```

#### Step by Step execution:

Given the same inputs as the previous example, I show you the execution step by step for `x = 2`, as you asked me.

After the `correct_outliers` call, the series is iterated with the apply function and at each element the `correct_outlier` function is applied, in the case in which the element under examination is `x = 2`, the step by step execution will be the following:

```
--- correct_outlier(), input: x: 2.0 threshold:5.0  n_prev: 3 n_next: 1
    step:
        if_condition: x is nan or x<threshold? True
            --- get_fixed_index(), input: current_index: 2 n_prev: 3 n_next: 1 
                step: if_condition: current_index-n_prev>=0? False 
                output: lower_index: 0 upper_index: 4 
            slice of series: [10. 20. 40. 50.] mean: 30.0
            @@@@ replace the value 2.0 with 30
```

---

### Extra

The `correct_outlier` and `correct_outliers` functions are not particularly efficient, mainly for these reasons:

1. The entire series is iterated in pure-Python and this is **never a good
   idea**. If possible, you should always use library functions for data
   analysis (such as Pandas, Numpy, ...) which are implemented in C/C++ and therefore some orders of magnitude more efficient than a pure python implementation.
2. We can do without the append function between two series, used in `correct_outliers`, we can solve the problem simply by doing a weighted average (which is obviously much faster)

The first point is the real bottleneck.

*How to solve?*

Below I propose two optimized solutions to the functions we have seen:

```
def correct_outliers_opt(s, threshold, n_prev=3, n_next=1):
    tmp_s = s.copy()
    tmp_s[tmp_s < threshold].to_frame().apply(lambda x: correct_outlier4(x, tmp_s, threshold), axis=1)
    return tmp_s

def correct_outlier_opt(x, s, threshold, n_prev=3, n_next=1):
    i = x.name
    lower_index, upper_index = get_fixed_index(x.name, n_prev, n_next)
    n = upper_index - lower_index
    mean = s.loc[lower_index:i-1].mean(skipna=True)*(i-lower_index)/n + ss.loc[i+1:upper_index].mean(skipna=True)*(upper_index-i)/n
    s[i] = mean
    return mean
```

The key point is within `correct_outliers_opt` and is the following:

```
tmp_s[tmp_s < threshold]
```

In this way I filter the series (taking advantage of the Pandas functions instead of pure python), before iterating it: in this way only the values ​​that satisfy the condition will be iterated. In our example we iterate in python only on the 2 values ​​we need to replace instead of iterating than the whole series.

The second thing that has been optimized (which has much less effect on performance than the previous point) is the calculation of the average within the function `correct_outlier_opt`: instead of making an append between the series now the average is calculated separately on the two series and then a weighted average is made to obtain a single result.

#### Comparison of execution times

Both receive the same inputs and return the same outputs, but with distinctly different execution times.

The execution times have been calculated on the following benchmarck instance:

```
threshold = 5
n_prev, n_next = 3, 1
N = 1000 

ss = pd.Series([10, 20, 2, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 0, 100] * N, dtype='float') # total len N * 10
```

correct_outliers:

```
%%timeit
correct_outliers(ss, threshold)
# Execution time: 2.95 s ± 417 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

optimized version:

```
%%timeit
correct_outliers_opt(ss, threshold)
#Execution time: 545 ms ± 16.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see the optimized version is about 6 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Can you please explain how 30.0 is being calculated in detail. Although result is correct but i am not able to understand the logic correctly

Comment: I tried to simplify the code to make it easier to understand, and I added step by step the input you asked for. Let me know if it's clearer now and upvote my answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def moving_average(vals):
    moving_vals = []
    size = len(vals)
    for (idx, val) in enumerate(vals):
        # determine the average for a given index
        if idx == 0 or idx == (size - 1):
            moving_vals.append(val)
            continue
        elif idx == 1:
            temp_arr = vals[2:4]
            temp_arr.append(vals[0])
            average = np.mean(temp_arr)
        elif idx == (size - 2):
            temp_arr = vals[size - 5:size - 3]
            temp_arr.append(vals[size - 1])
            average = np.mean(temp_arr)
        else:
            temp_arr = vals[idx - 2:idx]
            temp_arr1 = vals[idx + 1:idx + 3]
            average = np.mean(temp_arr + temp_arr1)

        # add to the final array based on the average
        if val < average:
            moving_vals.append(average)
        else:
            moving_vals.append(val)

    return moving_vals
```

This could be cleaned up, but I think the point is clear. For a problem like this you need to identify your corner cases and account for them and also handle the main case. In your example the corner case is when `idx = 1` or `idx = len(list) - 2`.

You could also handle the start and end of the array differently. In my code snippet those values will always be returned. Also, if you don't want to use numpy you can replace np.mean with mean from the math module.